# Use a database located on your local machine in Kubernetes pods

Tags: database, postgresql, kubernetes

I installed a PostgreSQL(14) DB on my WLS2 that is exposed on localhost port 5432 (127.0.0.1:5432).I would like my 5 kubernetes pods to interact with my database but I can't get them to communicate how can I do it (I run the kubernetes engine via docker desktop) ?

I've tried solutions like creating IP cluster services, external name or explicitly reporting the IP address and port inside the yaml manifests but they didn't work.

Comment: You will need to expose postgresql on a network interface that your kubernetes containers can see (so probably not localhost). Beyond that it will depend how you configure your networking.

Comment: Each Pod is its own localhost, plus each Node is its own localhost; when you say the database is "on localhost", where is it?  Can you run the database in a StatefulSet rather than outside the cluster?  Kubernetes is normally a multi-node environment; if you want a setup where you're running only on a local system, the application is in a container but the database isn't, would it be easier to use plain Docker?

Comment: @DavidMaze unfortunately this configuration was requested by the customer... local database and app that runs on 5 kubernetes pods

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help . I solve the problem. I had to modify the PostgreSQL database configuration files, postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf ( host-based authentication) to allow the DB to accept connections from external hosts, and then explicitly reporting in my Kubernetes manifests the IP address of the IPv4 ETH port of the host on which the DB was running.